# What do Stormtroopers wear when not wearing their armor?

Tags: star-wars, stormtroopers

Assuming Stormtroopers only wear their armor while on duty, what do they wear off-duty, sleeping, etc (Finn doesn't count)?

Comment: It is with great shame that I must report that I cannot find a picture of someone in a storm trooper helmet wearing a slave Leia costume.

Comment: Why doesn't Finn count?

Comment: I don't think very many storm troopers would be wearing Poe's bomber jacket, etc.

Comment: Pretty sure it's Under Armour. Don't forget to tip your waitress.

Comment: But Finn wasn't just wearing Poe's jacket. We *saw* him strip off his armour, and saw what he was wearing underneath. Is there any reason to think his clothes were atypical?

Answer (score 17):

First of all, we know Stormtrooper fashion originates from Clone Trooper fashion on Kamino:

**Kid fashion**
[image]

**Adult fashion**
[image]
[image]

The following points are true or probably true about the history of trooper fashion:

- When you're at war, off-duty uniform fashion is the last thing on everyone's minds, especially when national budgets are tight and your financiers are the enemy's banking corporations (for that matter, have any bank in any galaxy in any time period ever loaned people money for fashion?)
- During the rise of the Empire, the focus was on suppressing individuality and promoting monochrome fashion
- During the fall of the Empire and the rise of the First Order, the focus is on revamping the military's combat effectiveness to reconquer the galaxy. Again, off-duty fashion is the last thing on everyone's minds

Take, for example, Imperial-era kid fashion:
[image]

Therefore, what Finn is wearing underneath the armour he shedded:

[image]

is the closest we have to what a First Order Stormtrooper wears off-duty. It probably isn't too far off from what Imperial Stormtroopers wear. They probably couldn't be bothered to do a redesign.

Answer (score 1):

They wear uniforms exactly like Navy Officers do but just with different rank plates.
They have the DL-17 handgun and a commlink.

Something like this:

[image: example Imperial officer]